# Adjacent cells of multiple cell patches in a numpy array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, scipy

this is a followup question arising from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612663/counting-of-adjacent-cells-in-a-numpy-array).
The solution to count adjacent cells works pretty well unless you have multiple patches in the array.

So this time the array for instance looks like this.

```
import numpy
from scipy import ndimage

s = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2,2)
a = numpy.zeros((6,6), dtype=numpy.int) # example array
a[1:3, 1:3] = 1;a[2:4,4:5] = 1
print a
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 1 0 0 0]
[0 1 1 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]

# Number of nonoverlapping cells
c = ndimage.binary_dilation(a,s).astype(a.dtype)
b = c - a
numpy.sum(b) # returns 19
# However the correct number of non overlapping cells should be 22 (12+10)
```

Is there any smart solution to solve this dilemma without using any loops or iterating through the array? The reason is that the array could be quite big.

**idea 1:**

Just thought over it and a way to do it might be to check for more than one patch in the iterating structure. For the total count number to be correct those cells below have to be equal 2 (or more) in the dilation. Anyone got any idea how to turn this thought into code?

```
[1 1 1 1 0 0]
[1 0 0 2 1 1]
[1 0 0 2 0 1]
[1 1 1 2 0 1]
[0 0 0 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: What you got are the non-overlapping cells? Do you want them really individually for each patch? IE. what would you even want if you add `a[1,3:5] = 1` to your `a`?

Comment: see the answers in the other question. The array a above is just an example. My real arrays are really big and contain many cell patches of values

Comment: I'm quite confused, because you indicated that `scipy.signal.convolve2d` solved your previous problem -- but that counts all overlapping values. Now it seems you want _not_ to count overlaps, _except_ when those overlaps result from non-contiguous blocks of `1`s. That's a totally different requirement. So your previous question doesn't really help explain what you want now.

Comment: Does really huge mean you have many patches of ones or large patches? If they are few, I think my solution should work perfectly well

Comment: ohh sorry, back then i calculated the number of cells with overlaps, which also was the original question. Therefore this was the correct answer. No i want to calculate non-overlapping adjacent cells with multiple patches of values in an array. Huge means that the array is large and there are many different structured patches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `label` from `ndimage` to segment each patch of ones.

Then you just ask where the returned array equals 1, 2, 3 etc and perform your algoritm on it (or you just use the `ndimage.distance_transform_cdt` but with inverting your forground/background for each labeled segment.

**Edit 1:**

This code will take your array `a` and do what you ask:

```
b, c = ndimage.label(a)
e = numpy.zeros(a.shape)
for i in xrange(c):

    e += ndimage.distance_transform_cdt((b == i + 1) == 0) == 1

print e
```

I realize it is a bit ugly with all the equals there but it outputs:

```
In [41]: print e
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  2.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  2.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  2.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

**Edit 2 (Alternative solution):**

This code should do the same stuff and hopefully faster (however it will **not** find the where
two patches only touch corners).

```
b = ndimage.binary_closing(a) - a
b = ndimage.binary_dilation(b.astype(bool))

c = ndimage.distance_transform_cdt(a == 0) == 1

e = c.astype(numpy.int) * b + c

print e
```

Comment: and you want the chessboard setting (default) of the distance transform btw.

Comment: mhh, i know of the label function. Iam just reading through the doc of `ndimage.distance_transform_cdt`. Could you provide an example what you mean? My problem right now is that the counting of values by `numpy.sum` doesn't count adjacent cells patchwise

Comment: yeah, this works exactly like i wanted it. thanks. Although i still have no idea what the `distance_transform_cdt` does :-)

Comment: the `distance_transform_cdt` is a really nifty algorithm that will give the distance to the object for all non-object positions. Distance can be measured in many ways, and chessboard means it will give it in number of king's moves like if you were playing chess. So that is why I ask for the positions that return 1. (The taxicab would have needed to go two blocks for finding those of the corners (because it can't go diagonals))

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I should really dive more into the topic. By the way: i just tested your code on my real array. it works, however it is quite slow (most likely because of the long loop (c equals 2338 in my array).

Comment: if the restriction I put in the second solution is okay for your application, then I think it should be a faster algorithm.