# Optimizing implementation of a rotating mask in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

This is my first attempt at using strides in numpy and it did improve speed compared to simple iteration over the different filters, yet it still is quite slow (and it feels like there are at least one or two things that are completely redundant or inefficient).

So my question is: are there better ways of performing this or tweaks to my code that would make it significantly faster?

The algorithm performs a local evaluation of 9 different filters for each pixel and selects the one that has the least standard deviation (my attempt to implement Nagau and Matsuyma (1980) "A Structural Analysis of Complex Areal Photographs", as described in an image analysis book). The result is a both smoothened and edge sharpened image (Quite cool if you ask me!)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks

def get_rotating_kernels():

    kernels = list()

    protokernel = np.arange(9).reshape(3,  3)

    for k in xrange(9):

        ax1, ax2 = np.where(protokernel==k)
        kernel = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=bool)
        kernel[ax1: ax1+3, ax2: ax2+3] = 1
        kernels.append(kernel)

    return kernels


def get_rotation_smooth(im, **kwargs):

    kernels = np.array([k.ravel() for k in get_rotating_kernels()],
                dtype=bool)

    def rotation_matrix(section):

        multi_s = stride_tricks.as_strided(section, shape=(9,25),
            strides=(0, section.itemsize))

        rot_filters = multi_s[kernels].reshape(9,9)

        return rot_filters[rot_filters.std(1).argmin(),:].mean()

    return ndimage.filters.generic_filter(im, rotation_matrix, size=5, **kwargs)

from scipy import lena
im = lena()
im2 = get_rotation_smooth(im)
```

(Just a comment, the `get_rotating_kernel` hasn't really been optimized since almost no time is spent there anyway)

On my netbook, it took 126s and Lena is after all a quite small image.

**Edit:**

I got the suggestion to change `rot_filters.std(1)` to `rot_filters.var(1)` to save quite a few square-roots and it shaved off something in the order of 5s.

Comment: Have you tried profiling it (with e.g. `cProfile`)?

Comment: Actually I haven't since I figured that because the `rotation_matrix` function is called 262144 times, there's the time that can be saved. And whichever part it would point to I still don't know how it would help me...but maybe it's just that I haven't learned to love `cProfile`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will have a difficult time optimizing significantly using Python + `scipy`. However, I was able to make a small improvement by using `as_strided` to generate `rot_filters` directly, rather than through boolean indexing. This is based on a very simple n-dimensional `windows` function. (I wrote it to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12612663/577088) before I realized that a 2d convolution function exists in `scipy`.) The following code provides a modest 10% speedup on my machine; see below for an explanation of how it works:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks

# pass in `as_strided` as a default arg to save a global lookup
def rotation_matrix2(section, _as_strided=stride_tricks.as_strided):
    section = section.reshape(5, 5)  # sqrt(section.size), sqrt(section.size)
    windows_shape = (3, 3, 3, 3)     # 5 - 3 + 1, 5 - 3 + 1, 3, 3
    windows_strides = section.strides + section.strides
    windows = _as_strided(section, windows_shape, windows_strides)
    rot_filters = windows.reshape(9, 9)
    return rot_filters[rot_filters.std(1).argmin(),:].mean()

def get_rotation_smooth(im, _rm=rotation_matrix2, **kwargs):
    return ndimage.filters.generic_filter(im, _rm, size=5, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.misc import lena
    im = lena()
    im2 = get_rotation_smooth(im)
    #plt.gray()      # Uncomment these lines for
    #plt.imshow(im2) # demo purposes.
    #plt.show()
```

The above function `rotation_matrix2` is equivalent to the following two functions (which together are actually a bit slower than your original function, because `windows` is more generalized). This does exactly what your original code does -- creates 9 3x3 windows into a 5x5 array, and then reshapes them into a 9x9 array for processing.

```
def windows(a, w, _as_strided=stride_tricks.as_strided):
    windows_shape = tuple(sa - sw + 1 for sa, sw in zip(a.shape, w))
    windows_shape += w
    windows_strides = a.strides + a.strides
    return _as_strided(a, windows_shape, windows_strides)

def rotation_matrix1(section, _windows=windows):
    rot_filters = windows(section.reshape(5, 5), (3, 3)).reshape(9, 9)
    return rot_filters[rot_filters.std(1).argmin(),:].mean()
```

`windows` works with arrays of any dimension, as long as the window has the same number of dimensions. Here's a breakdown of how it works:

```
    windows_shape = tuple(sa - sw + 1 for sa, sw in zip(a.shape, w))
```

We can think of the `windows` array as a n-d array of n-d arrays. The shape of the outer n-d array is dictated by the window's degrees of freedom within the larger array; in every dimension, the number of positions the window can take is equal to the length of the larger array minus the length of the window plus one. In this case, we have a 3x3 window into a 5x5 array, so the outer 2-d array is a 3x3 array.

```
    windows_shape += w
```

The shape of the inner n-d array is the same as the shape of the window itself. In our case, this is again a 3x3 array.

Now for the strides. We have to define the strides for the outer n-d array, and for the inner n-d array. But it turns out that they're the same! After all, the window moves through the larger array in just the same way that an individual index moves through the array, right?

```
    windows_strides = a.strides + a.strides
```

Now we have all the information we need to create the windows:

```
    return _as_strided(a, windows_shape, windows_strides)
```

Comment: I moved the `windows_strides` definition outside of the def and changed `std(1)` to `var(1)` and I think as you pointed out that it's not much more to do here python-wise.

Answer (score 1):

For complex per-pixel + neighbourhood operations you may consider using cython to improve performances. It allows to efficiently write code as for-loops in a close to python syntax which is later-on converted to C-code.

For inspiration you can take a look at the scikit-image code for instance :

https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/filter/_denoise.pyx